# Why isn't myXMLHttpRequest() defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use PHP to read from a text file and display a random word definition pair.

```
function fetchTerm() {
  var myXMLRequest = new XMlHttpRequest(); 
  myXMLRequest.onload = createRandomWordDefin;    
  myXMLRequest.open("GET", "play.php", true);    
  myXMLRequest.send();    
}

function createRandomWordDefin() {
  var json = JSON.parse(this.resonseText);
  document.getElementById("defin").innerHTML = json.defintion;
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = json.word;
}
```

-The web app relies on a text file containing a culinary term, a culinary category for the term, and a definition.
-Allow the user to specify a culinary category in which to build a quiz question.
-Build the question by opening the text file and randomly selecting a term. Select three possible definitions from the text file and build a multiple-choice button selection. Respond "correct" or "incorrect" to all button selections.

Comment: can you please describe the problem???

Comment: `XMlHttpRequest` should be `XMLHttpRequest`. Typo.

Comment: As long as you don't show any php code, this question is not related to php. However, you should check in a browser that your invoked php code is really sending what you expect it to send. Use the browser's developer tools to debug and see the error messages, to inspect if your callback is invoked at all, and with what actual arguments. If none helps, then only you should come and ask.

Comment: Your `resonseText` is a typo (1st line of `createRandomWordDefIn`). Should be `responseText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo, I should have put XMLHttpRequest and instead I put, XMlHttpRequest.